Get previous sentence while using SpaCy matcher
I am running a SpaCy Matcher line-by-line on a text file. My file has each text entry on a separate line. I am trying to extract 1) the matched instance, 2) the full sentence, and 3) the previous sentence. I am able to get the first two, but I am having trouble getting the previous sentence, given that there isn't a sentence index (from this post). Here is my code:
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in iter(f.readline, ''):
        doc = nlp(line)
        matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
        matcher.add("pattern_of_interest", [pattern])
        matches = matcher(doc)
    
        for match_id, start, end in matches:
            string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
            span = doc[start:end] 
            
        for sent in doc.sents:
            if matcher(sent):
                instances.append(pd.Series({"instance":str(span.text), 
                                        "sentence":str(sent.text),
                                        "previous_sentence":str(sent[-1].text)}))

I understand that the bolded part is giving me the previous token, not sentence (I tried to get around this with the list, but it doesn't work). Any advice for retrieving the previous sentence would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Adjustments:
Track Previous Sentence: We now maintain a prev_sent variable that tracks the previous sentence as we iterate through all sentences in a document. Matcher Usage: We only need to create the Matcher instance once, outside the loop through lines in the file, and then apply it to each sentence within the loop. This is more efficient than recreating it for every line. Check for Previous Sentence: We handle cases where there might not be a previous sentence (e.g., the match is found in the first sentence of the document) by checking if prev_sent is None. If it is, we set the "previous_sentence" field to "N/A" or any placeholder text you find suitable.
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
import pandas as pd

# Load the SpaCy model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")  # Adjust model as necessary

# Define your pattern here
pattern = [{"LOWER": "example"}]  # Example pattern

# Initialize matcher with the vocab
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("pattern_of_interest", [pattern])

instances = []  # List to hold match details

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in iter(f.readline, ''):
        doc = nlp(line)
        
        prev_sent = None  # Variable to keep track of the previous sentence
        for sent in doc.sents:
            matches = matcher(sent)
            if matches:
                for match_id, start, end in matches:
                    instance_text = sent[start:end].text  # The matched instance
                    current_sentence = sent.text
                    previous_sentence = prev_sent.text if prev_sent else "N/A"  # Handle the case where there's no previous sentence
                    
                    # Append the extracted information to your instances list
                    instances.append(pd.Series({"instance": instance_text, 
                                                 "sentence": current_sentence,
                                                 "previous_sentence": previous_sentence}))
            prev_sent = sent  # Update the previous sentence for the next iteration

# Convert instances list to DataFrame
df_instances = pd.DataFrame(instances)
print(df_instances)

